# pip install for python in visual studio code does not work properly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

I have installed pip, but whenever I try to install any module it doesn't work at all with visual studio code. the issue is probably just a directory change. but anywhere I search doesn't give me any answers. any module I download I can't physically use.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Please clarify what you tried to install and what didn't work.  What errors you got and how you installed.  What python version?

Comment: Are you using a virtual env? If so, is VS Code configured for the same virtual env as the one where you install the modules?

Answer (score 0):

In the path environment variable, add the path of `scripts directory` in the python installation package.

For example, my path is:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
```

Comment: this wasnt the issue i just downloaded some pip manager then installed through there.